# Ruby "gem generate" indexer broken with XML Builder 3.0.0. How to fix?

Tags: ruby, xml, rubygems, builder

Problem: gem generate fails because it's missing XML Builder.

```
  $ gem generate
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Gem::Indexer requires that the XML Builder library be installed:
      gem install builder
```

How to fix this?

Comment: That's good. And where's the question?

Comment: @DNNX the question is how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: edit rubygem source code file indexer.rb to require the older Builder.

```
gem 'builder', '~> 2.1'
require 'builder/xchar'
```

Comment: @Pixoo I haven't looked for a general solution if you can't modify rubygems. Heroku has a great support team and they have modified a gem for me before, so if Heroku is showing you this error I think their team will have good ideas about how to solve it.